# Is seperate language installation required after installing IDE?

Tags: python, ide, jupyter, spyder

I want to install Python on my windows 10 64 bit
However I cant figure out which IDE is best for GUI application building
I've tried using ActivePython but its not compatible with x64 processors
**I want to use both Matplotlib and Tkinter in my program
So which IDE is best for the same purpose??**
Furthermore what is the stepwise procedure to install environment for the same??
**Is separate Python installation required after installing any IDE??**
e.g., if I install Jupyter/Spyder on my PC, is there any requirement to download Python 3.9 setup from python.org??

Answer (score 2):

I personally recommend PyCharm community edition. It's a free IDE and it is great because it allows you to integrate anaconda environments by default. Yes, you will have to install python and anaconda, but once you get it setup, it's a great IDE to work in.

Pycharm can support any version of Windows (x86, x64), Linux or Mac. Installing it is simple, first install the [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) installer, then the [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads) installer, then go to [this website](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) (Pycharm download location) and once the installer is downloaded, run it and select your preferences. To setup an environment, anaconda has a built in navigation tool which allows you to edit environments, but Pycharm will also allow you to set it up within the IDE.

Comment: Pycharm is no where near the word beginner-friendly :( VSCode is much better in my opinion.

Comment: @CoolCloud Okay, well it's up to you, just making a recommendation. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

### First off: Welcome To Stackoverflow!!

It depend on the IDE, **if you are concerned about Jupyter** the IDE **does not** come with python
source:[https://realpython.com/jupyter-notebook-introduction/#:~:text=The%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20is%20not,distributions%20of%20the%20Python%20language](https://realpython.com/jupyter-notebook-introduction/#:%7E:text=The%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20is%20not,distributions%20of%20the%20Python%20language).

If you don't care about all the fancy functionality and other bells and whistles you could just use `IDLE` which comes pre-installed with python.

A few IDE'S that are widely used and supported are:

---

**Atom**  For: (Beginner, Professional) , Pricing: Free

**PyCharm**: For: (Professional)   ,  Pricing: (Freemium)

**Visual Studio Code** : For(Professional) , Pricing:(Free)

**Spyder** :For: (Beginner, Professional)     Pricing: (Free)

**Sublime Text 3** : For: (Beginner, Professional)     Pricing: (Freemium)

---

Source:[https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/ide#:~:text=PyCharm%20provides%20all%20major%20features,favorite%20IDE%20for%20Python%20development](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/ide#:%7E:text=PyCharm%20provides%20all%20major%20features,favorite%20IDE%20for%20Python%20development).

Answer (score 1):

VS code is the most popular one.
It is freely available and handles all languages including `Python`

here is the link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/